# MySQL Year() doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to get an overview over how many hours someone worked in a year, the monthly and weekly hours were no problem but when I try to get it to work with the `year()` function it just gives me `"2.016"` and `"2.017"` instead of the actual year and just 12 hours instead of the actual ones

```
select 
    Year(Date) AS Year,WorkerID, 
    Date_format(sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(goes)-time_to_sec(comes))), '%h:%i') as H 
FROM 
    Info 
Group by 
    Year, WorkerID
```

Comment: Please provide table structure (`CREATE TABLE`) and some example data so we can help you. Are you sure your MySQL Client parses the returned values right? Also what is your MySQL Client / Driver?

Comment: do you get that Format(2.016) on your console, or are you checking the results in Excel?

Comment: I'm using wine, i the 2.016 results on there.

don't really know how to provide actual useful information :/

Comment: I have something similar. I have cols `start` and `stop` saved as timestamp _(YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s)_ and then I get summary of seconds (divide by 3600 to get hours) for each year with this: `SELECT YEAR(start) AS year, SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stop) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) AS total FROM report_log_items GROUP BY year` - there are some wheres, but this is main logic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some part of your environment where you are viewing output is adding a default fullstop as 1000 separator so 2017 becomes 2.017. Therefore, check default settings on the output side and remove default separator.